# Migrate from 2.2.1 to 2.3 CE

Tags: magento2, migration, version

I have to redo a magento website from 2.1 CE to 2.3 CE. There are few orders with total sales of 230$. what is better to create from scratch and migrate customers and orders? or is there a way by applying patch?

Comment: It will be better to go for updated magento version.Since the original website is above 2.X it wont be difficult to upgrade to latest version.

Comment: thanks ill try the same

Comment: You can upgrade your Magento from 2.2.1 to 2.3. You can refer:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252867/upgrade-magento-2-1-13-to-2-3-0/287262#287262

Comment: thanks David it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade your Magento 2.2.1 to 2.3. You can refer:
[upgrade magento 2.1.13 to 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252867/upgrade-magento-2-1-13-to-2-3-0/287262#287262)

Hope it helps you!

Comment: this worked perfectly for me with many tweaks even with documentations . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used this link to upgrade from Magento 2.2 to 2.3.

[Command-line upgrade](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade Magento version 2.3.3 use below commands.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Magento 2.3 Supported PHP versions.

```
~7.1.3
~7.2.0
~7.3.0
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version using below command.

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This will not work. Composer will generate errors.