# Migrate Data from Ver 2.1.2 to new with Ver dev-2.3-develop

Tags: magento-2.1.2

I have new website Ver dev-2.3-develop and i want to migrate the data of the products and media file from the old one 
the old one is Ver 2.1.2 
so is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgrade magento 2.1.13 to 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252867/upgrade-magento-2-1-13-to-2-3-0)

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/upgrade-with-script.html